# how to sync two related projects with each other preferably with git?

Tags: git, github

We have two separate webshop projects `Webshop A` and `Webshop B`. They are both in a repository on github. `Webshop B` is basically a copy of `Webshop A` with few changes, but a lot of functionality stays the same.

Right now when we change something in `Websop A` needed in `Webshop B` also, we just copy+paste the necessary code to the other project. Is there a way to do it through Git?

We basically want to pick changes from `Webshop A` to `Webshop B`, in some cases from `Webshop B` to `Webshop A` but not everything.

Comment: If you want to only copy over certain commits, then you can use ```git cherry-pick <commit-hash>```.

Answer (score 0):

One possible approach:

Have one git repository with two branches `shop A` and `shop B`. (You can further extend on this according to your git workflow, e.g. `shop A develop` and `shop A master` etc.)

When a new feature shall be used for both shops, make a new branch `feature xyz`, develop the feature and make a pull request / merge of `feature xyz` into both branches `shop A` and `shop B`.

If you only make tiny adjustments, e.g. bugfixes, you can use [cherry pick](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick) to select certain commits to go into your branches.